# Pop a page from stack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to navigate from Home Page(in shared code) to Detail Page(in the droid,native code). I want to remove the Detail Page and go back to the Home Page when someone press the Accept button.  Navigation.PopAsync() does not work for me.

Comment: If you use open the last page with Navigation.PushAsync(); you can use PopAsync. But probably you open another method. Do you share your passing page code?

Comment: How are you navigating from the home page to the detail page in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to navigate from Home Page(in shared code) to Detail Page(in the droid,native code).

As I  understand, your Detail Page(in the droid,native code),  it's an [Activity](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/). You need using [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/#Overview) to open an `Activity` from `Xamarin.Forms`. 
You could read my answer about [Start an Android activity in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338217/start-an-android-activity-in-xamarin-forms/44339481#44339481)
.

> I want to remove the Detail Page and go back to the Home Page when someone press the Accept button.

You just need to close the newly opened `Activity`, for example :

```
public class NativeActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.native_layout);
        Button native_bt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.native_bt);
        native_bt.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            //close the current Activity and go back to the Home Page.
            this.Finish();
        };
    }
}
```