# Call PCL method in background Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, printer-control-language

im currently working on a xamarin.forms app (only android at the moment). This app should perform some tasks if a bluetooth device is connected (app is not running). The task is to collect some data from sensors and write it do sqlite database.

I managed to catch bluetooth events using broadcastreceivers ...

My question is How should i collect and write those data (GPS) ?

Can i just call them  through some events in PCL ? 
Or do i need some services ? Or should i create that funcionality in .android project ?

Im a newbie in xamarin and android so i appreciate any help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> My question is How should i collect and write those data (GPS) ? Can i just call them through some events in PCL ? Or do i need some services ? Or should i create that funcionality in .android project ?

There are several ways to get the sensors data, you could so this in your `PCL`.

## Method 1 :

When you  catch `bluetooth` events in your `BroadcastReceiver`, you could get sensors data in the `OnReceive` method.

## Method 2 :

You could use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to get the device sensors data and then  write it do `sqlite` database. As the document said :

> Xamarin.Forms allows developers to define behavior in platform-specific projects. DependencyService then finds the right platform implementation, allowing shared code to access the native functionality.

About `DependencyService` usage you could read the document or refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338217/start-an-android-activity-in-xamarin-forms/44339481#44339481).

## Method 3 :

You could use [DeviceMotionPlugin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/devicemotionplugin) to get these sensors data. When you use this plugin, you can call `CrossDeviceMotion.Current` from any project or `PCL` to gain access to APIs.

## Update :

You could do implement this function in your `PCL`. When you use `method 2` or `method 3`, you could get the sensors data in `PCL` and then you could store these into your sqlite. **Still use native Android API to get sensors data in native Android, but you could use these data in `PCL`**.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer , so i need to move the gps functionality (geolocator plugin) and sqlite functions to .android project. Call these in OnReceive() in background and when the app is running call them using DependencyService. Right ?

Comment: @boris_dv, I have update my answer, if there is any problem, please feel free to ask.